# Sed problem creating correct regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

A pretty basic question, but one that i can't seem to find the answer to on stackoverflow or elsewhere online that actually solves the issue.

I'm writing a simple bash script to batch process a bunch of files.  The script is feed by a directory listing, and then processes them individually.  Unfortunately, the format of each filename may vary, and that's where I'm running into my trouble.  Below is a sample of the type of filenames I am working with and the script that I am working with.

P.S. I'm sure there is probably some way to do this with awk as well (or any number of unix tools, but for now I'm focusing on sed).

Thanks in advance:

**Files:**

```
/home/acct/Foo-Bar.fl
/home/acct/Foo-1.1.fl
/home/acct/Cat-3.4-500.fl
/home/acct/DOG-BEAR-4.4-1.1.fl
/home/acct/DOG-BEAR-4.4-UPDATED.fl
```

I'm trying to extract the full path, filename, version number, and file prefix from each of these lines.  Below is my latest attempt:

```
DIR_PATH="/home/acct/
for i in `find ${DIR_PATH}`;
do
FILEPATH="$i"
FILENAME=`echo $i | sed -e "s#${DIR_PATH}##g"`
FILEPREFIX=`echo $FILENAME | sed -e "s/\(.*\)-[0-9]\+.*/\1/g"`
FILEVERSION=`echo $FILENAME | sed -e "s/.*-\([0-9]\+.*\)\.fl/\1/g`
echo "$DIR_PATH"
echo "$FILE_PATH"
echo "$FILENAME"
echo "$FILEPREFIX"
echo "$FILEVERSION"
    #do something with this file now that I know what is going on with it
done
```

Trouble comes into play when dealing with version numbers separated by "dashes" and files without a version number.  I think i've gotten all the issues with complex version numbers resolved, but am still struggling with the cases where no version number exists at all.

I figure I need to do some sort of either or type expression (or have a second sed statement to do another pass), but am not really sure how to format it.

**UPDATE:**

Per Axel's comment, determining the filename can be made much easier by using *basename* instead of trying to match the path.  Also, an answer down below involved splitting the filename from the extension, also a change that I think would be worth incorporating.

I would update the script with thsee changes to be similar to:

```
FILEPATH="$i"
FILENAME=`basename $i`
FILENAMENOSUFFIX=`echo $FILENAME | sed -e "s/\(.*\)\..*/\1/g"`
FILEPREFIX=`echo $FILENAME | sed -e "s/\(.*\)-[0-9]\+.*/\1/g"`
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems. —Jamie Zawinsky

Comment: At least for the filename, you should use FILENAME=`basename $i`. It simply works (even if the name includes a hash '#'...

Comment: Axel, that is a great not (hadn't used basename before).  That is a much better technique for stripping the directory information from the filename.  Major help!

Comment: @Joey: [Obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/208/)

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash (except for `find`):

```
shopt -s extglob
while read -r file
do
    dir=${file%/*}
    name=${file##*/}
    noext=${name/%.fl}
    pre=${noext%%-@([0-9])*}
    ver=${noext/#$pre-}
    [[ ${#ver} == ${#noext} ]] && ver=
    echo "Dir: $dir, Name: $name, Noext: $noext"
    echo "   Pre: $pre, Ver: $ver"
done < <(find "$dir" -type f)
```

Output using your example filenames:

```
Dir: /home/acct, Name: Foo-Bar.fl, Noext: Foo-Bar
   Pre: Foo-Bar, Ver: 
Dir: /home/acct, Name: Foo-1.1.fl, Noext: Foo-1.1
   Pre: Foo, Ver: 1.1
Dir: /home/acct, Name: Cat-3.4-500.fl, Noext: Cat-3.4-500
   Pre: Cat, Ver: 3.4-500
Dir: /home/acct, Name: DOG-BEAR-4.4-1.1.fl, Noext: DOG-BEAR-4.4-1.1
   Pre: DOG-BEAR, Ver: 4.4-1.1
Dir: /home/acct, Name: DOG-BEAR-4.4-UPDATED.fl, Noext: DOG-BEAR-4.4-UPDATED
   Pre: DOG-BEAR, Ver: 4.4-UPDATED
```

Comment: Dennis, thanks for the response.  While more bash than i was looking for, this is something that can easily be followed and understood.  I also like the idea of breaking out the No-extension version as an intermediary step.  You can then do a simple comparison to determine if a version was present and act accordingly.  While this is a very simplistic example, your answer was easy to follow and provides a basis for future iterations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type file | sed 's!\(.*\)/\([^/0-9]*\)-\([0-9][^/]*\)\.\([^./]*\)$!\0 \1 \2 \3 \4!'
```

This assumes each file is setup like this: {base}/{prefix}-{version-starts-with-number}.{extension}

Comment: Jon, this does look to work, thank you, but it a bit hard to read and parse from an initial viewing.  I'm not sure if your command addresses it, but not all files may have a {version-starts-with-number} section, and that's what is causing the issues above.